# Python Pandas conditional row merge

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to python and Pandas and I was looking for this answer for the past few weeks, but I hit a brick wall. Although, I normally find my answers in here or somewhere else on the net - I wasn't lucky this time.

Problem:

I have an excel file which I need to loop through to create a script for a firewall.

Column A, row 1,2,3 are merged and contains one Hostname
Column B, row 1,2,3 are not merged and each row contains one IP address each

How do I write a condition to say if column A has any merged rows then check and merge the same row's in column B?

## My Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheetname="sheet_name")

df1 = df['Unnamed: 2'].dropna().drop([6,7]) # Unanamed is the column ID then Delete empty cell's and delete row 6&7
df2 = df['Unnamed: 4'].dropna().drop([6,7]) # Unanamed is the column ID then Delete empty cell's and delete row 6&7

for a, b in zip(df1,df2):
  # The condition I am looking for, please note the code below is not correct
  if a is merged then merge b:
      print('Hostname {} ip address {}'.format(a,b))
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks!, I have updated my question.

Comment: did my solution work?

Comment: Hi gyoza, thanks for the solution. I am actually looking for automated way of scanning the excel file with an "If" statement. Something like.

Comment: If column A is merged then merge same row's in column B or something similar. So I want to check if the cell contains data and if it is merged Cells - I want to then merge the same number of cells on all Cells on its right.  Example in the screenshot you can see Column B being single rows but in column F cells are merged. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: OK, then let me delete my previous solution since it seems it is not what you need.

Comment: Gyoza, your code actually resolved most of the problem - I just need a way to automate your output, so kindly put your solution back. Is there a way to put a condition around your solution, so the program checks and formats automatically?

Comment: OK I updated my solution by adding 2nd paragraph... Hope I captured your intention, but if not feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load only the input part (red square in your question) as `df`, and if the column `'Host name'` is merged, it would look like this (`df`)

```
Host name IP address
LAX_R     192.168.1.1
NaN       192.168.1.2
NaN       192.168.1.3
```

By the way, you can check if the column `'Host name'` is initially merged by checking if it contains `NaN` value (Note: I'm assuming there should not be `NaN` values if it is not initially merged):

```
if sum(df['Host name'].isnull()) > 0:
```

And then, by forward filling NaN,

```
df.ffill(inplace=True)
```

we get

```
Host name IP address
LAX_R     192.168.1.1
LAX_R     192.168.1.2
LAX_R     192.168.1.3
```

After that, `IP address` of the same `Host name` are aggregated to the same cell as a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Host name')['IP address'].apply(list))
```

At this point, df looks like this

```
           IP address
Host name   
LAX_R      [192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3]
```

The next step is to remove some unnecessary characters

```
df.columns = ['IP address']
for ch in ["[", "]", ",", "'"]:
    df['IP address'] = df['IP address'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(ch, ""))
```

(Optional) For "Apache Open Office", displaying each IP address in new line is done by

```
df['IP address'] = df['IP address'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "\n"))
```

Finally save it.

```
df.to_excel("yourfile.xlsx", index=True)
```

---

(Appendix)
For "Microsoft Office", displaying each IP address in new line is done by

1. Skip (Optional) part above
2. Choose column "IP address"
3. Choose Home --> Wrap Text as the following red square

[image: Choose Home-->Wrap Text]

It's a bit lengthy, but it should do the task.
Hope it helps.